# Stream rtsp to Html5 video tag

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, rtsp

I have a camera with a RTSP stream
(Example: rtsp://admin:password@ip:554/Streaming/Channels/101),
now I want to stream it using HTML5 without any plugin.

I tried some solutions using http-flv protocol:

1.Nginx-http-flv-module + FFmpeg + flv.js

2.Nodejs + FFmpeg + flv.js

**ffmpeg command:** rtsp://admin:password@ip:554/Streaming/Channels/101-vcodec copy -an -f flv -s 800x600 rtmp://localhost:1935/myapp/test

[ffmpeg log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Z9NL.png)

The problem is that latency is high bettween 5s-8s, if there is any solution to reduce latency between 1s-2s.

PS:flv.js is an HTML5 Flash Video (FLV) Player written in pure JavaScript without Flash. [flv.js](https://github.com/Bilibili/flv.js/)

Comment: Show your ffmpeg command and the complete log.

Comment: I posted them on my question, please review it. Thanks.

Comment: 5-8 seconds is actually pretty good. I think you may struggle to get better than that without suing RTPS or WebRTC

Answer (score 0):

For reducing latency, I use ffmpeg command( **-tune zerolatency -preset ultrafast**), then the latency will be under 3 seconds.