# Merge video and audio in <video> in Javascript

Tags: javascript, audio, video, ffmpeg

I need to play an AAC file at the same time as an MP4 file. Is this possible with the Javascript browser?

I tried to use ffmpeg on the server, but there is a problem of content length mismatch regarding AAC files (I have to do it on the fly). But I have a preference to do it in the browser.

I've already searched many forums but couldn't find what I wanted to do.

Comment: ffmpeg on the server likely can do the job for you. Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66658044/4516027) (assuming video & audio are ok)? As for your error, please include the commands you tried with the log message.

Comment: @kesh first of all thanks, I tried "ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.aac -c copy -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -f mp4 pipe:1", and I pipe the process to the client (I'm using express js) (only with video it works, but only audio or video with audio it doesn't work) But I think I found the problem: I tried to output to a file and it says "Malformed AAC bitstream detected: use the audio bitstream filter 'aac_adtstoasc' to fix it ('-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc' option with ffmpeg)
av_interleaved_write_frame() : Operation not permitted. I'll try to fix this error and come back to you as soon as possible

Comment: omg, the problem is fixed, thank you for pointing me in the right direction! bye